# Does homology of a trait necessarily imply that the most recent common ancestor had the trait?

Tags: evolution, homology

If two different species have a trait that is homologous, does this mean that the most recent common ancestor necessarily had the same trait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, assuming you treat the term strictly.**

The term **[homologous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(biology))** implies that the most recent common ancestor had the trait, although it would be possible for the term to be used in error, when something thought to be a homology is actually not.

If the trait is shared but the trait evolved separately twice, instead you would refer to it as an *analogous* trait rather than homologous; analogous traits are often the result of **[convergent evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution)**.

I can imagine some edge cases, however, where one could argue about homology, although I don't have a specific example in mind (maybe someone can help me out if they can think of one). Imagine you have a trait that is present in an ancestral population, becomes minimized in a common ancestor, and then multiple species descending from that ancestor start to exhibit the trait again. This is called [atavism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atavism). In some ways, atavism could be seen as convergent evolution and an analogous trait: each has separately evolved that trait from the last common ancestor. However, one would expect a lot more genetic similarity than other examples of convergent evolution and therefore outside of cladistics it might be more appropriate to think of it as a homologous trait in that you can find *some* ancestor that shared the trait, it just doesn't happen to be the most recent one.